# hibernate query

Tags: sql, hibernate, join

I'm trying to carry out the following query using hibernate's construct SQL query:

```
SELECT thi FROM track_history_items thi 
JOIN (SELECT max(id) distinct_id FROM track_history_items WHERE type='TrackBroadcast' GROUP BY artist_id) distinctIds 
ON distinctIds.distinct_id = thi.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

however there seems to be a problem with using parentheses.  Can anyone tell me the proper way to form this query for hibernate?  Thanks in advance!

----**UPDATE**----

I've tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM TrackHistoryItems thi 
WHERE id 
IN (SELECT max(id) 
  FROM TrackHistoryItems 
  WHERE type='TrackBroadcast' 
  GROUP BY artist_id) 
ORDER BY createdAt DESC;
```

but it takes forever (i.e. long enough that I've yet to see it complete as of writing).

Please can someone help with this - I'm sure there must be a simple way of achieving what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't support subqueries in `from`. However, this query can be rewritten as follows:

```
SELECT thi FROM track_history_items thi 
WHERE id IN (SELECT max(id) FROM track_history_items 
            WHERE type='TrackBroadcast' GROUP BY artist_id)    
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

If performance of this query is not satisfactory, there are no other options except for using [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html).

Comment: this won't work, as the subquery returns more than one row (in fact it will return the max id for each group of TrackBroadcasts that have the same artist_id)

Comment: @axtavt see my above edit - this doesn't load (on my local machine it simply carries on running indefinitely, on my test server it gives a proxy error)

Comment: unfortunately when I tried a native query I got a 'No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1' error...

Comment: @tiswas: With `addEntity()`? It's quite strange.

Comment: how would you use addEntity in this case?  I was simply using setting the full query and using constructSQLQuery..

Comment: @tiswas: See the link in the answer. It should work fine if you inform Hibernate on expected result types with `addEntity()` or `addScalar()`.